# Is it safe to only splice the hot wires to new switches?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have an old house and in my basement I have a 4 gang switch box for some ceiling lights.  I want to move 2 of those switches to another wall (technically to another room, as I have built a wall splitting up one large room into 2).

The problem is that the wiring is in metal conduits and are not in predictable locations in the ceiling. I would have to tear out a town of ceiling to find where these cables are and that sucks because the ceiling (and walls) are all plaster on drywall. It would be a huge mess and PITA to tear it all out.

So Im wondering if I can splice the hot wires *only* for the 2 switches in question and run the new Romex over to the new switches and only connect the hot wire?

Or do I NEED to also splice the white/neutral wire too?  The reason I ask is because it looks like all the white wires in this box are just spliced together which in it self makes me nervous because I know for a fact that these 4 switches are spread over 2 different circuits.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why is connecting wires in a box of concern?

Answer (score 3):

Start by learning to work with metal conduit.  I get that you come from the cable world (or have absorbed Youtube videos from the cable world) but metal conduit is excellent and you're better off skilling up into it so that you're more comfortable with it.   Also, the usual reason you find conduit in a home is because Romex is illegal in that jurisdiction, e.g. Chicagoland. If you use it, you'll have to disclose the defect when you sell the house.

First is identifying wires in conduit.  You open up all the boxes, unfasten the switches/receptacles, and straighten the wires enough that they can move freely by an inch or so (i.e. aren't making a sharp turn as they exit the box). With luck, they'll be identified clearly or obviously.  If not, you can pull or push on the wires in one box and inch or so, and see what moves in another box.  If it doesn't want to move, it may be passing through a different box, but you can pull or push on the pass-thru to find the other end of it.  I usually find just 1 inch of movement is enough, then pull the wire back the inch.

If you need to tell 1 wire from others in a run, hold the other wires still while pulling the one you want to identify until it increases resistance.  You'll find that one is taut in the other box.

Feel free to use colored electrical tape to identify wires for your own purposes, e.g. I like to use red for switched-hot, blue for alternate switched-hot, yellow for both travelers in a 3-way*, blue for "alternate" pair of travelers, etc.

The wire in use is called THHN wire. Better lumber yards and hardware stores (not necessarily big-box stores) will cheerfully sell several colors by-the-foot at sane cost; try to avoid the small spools at the box stores as they are overpriced by comparison.  In 500' quantity the stuff goes for about 18 cents a foot. Conduit really shines as wires get larger - 50A EV charging happens at #8 wire which costs 60 cents a foot.

---

---

---

*  There is no useful use to distinguishing the travelers from each other; you see red/black in the drawings on the Internet simply because that's how cables are made.  I use individual wires in conduit, and I own 10 colors, so I use yellow-yellow for 3-ways.

Answer (score -1):

You've probably got a multi wired branch circuit installed there which would have only one neutral from the panel. You'd want to verify that. Extending only the hot and switched hot would be extending a switch loop which isn't allowed because new switch location now require a neutral. Running new NM cable might not be allowed in your area if metal conduit is required. If it's allowed, run 3#12 or 3#14, which ever you're extending and include the neutral.

Comment: There is zero evidence in the question of an MWBC. Having lighting on one would be fairly unusual.

Comment: @nobody  Two circuits and all white wires connected give the probability of a MWBC. That's why I said to verify it. Lighting used to be  done on these all the time especially in conduit installations. The breakers weren't handle-tied so it was harder to tell them.